# how to get result from Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am developing an application on Windows Phone 8, I want to ask that is there any ways to get result from the MessageBox.Show while MessageBox is wrapped in Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke? for example:

```
  Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            });
```

I want to get the user's choice, what should I do? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to do this is to use a call back which passes along the result

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
  var result = MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
  OnMessageBoxComplete(result);
});

void OnMessageBoxComplete(MessageBoxResult result) { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks JaredPar. I used a SycnInvokeHelper to convert that into a sync call.

Comment: internal class SyncInvokeHelper
    {
        public void Invoke()
        {
            if (this.dispatcher.CheckAccess() == true)
            {
                this.Execute();
            }
            else
            {
                this.dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ExecuteBody(this.Execute));
            }
        }

        private void Execute()
        {
            this.Result = this.execBody.DynamicInvoke(args);
            if (this.Completed != null)
            {
                this.Completed(this);
            }
        }
    }